# What code is actually executed "multi-threadedly" in async/await pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

In this code:

```
public async Task v_task()
{
    await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello!"));
}

public async void v1()
{
    await v_task();
    // some other actions...
}

public void ButtonClick()
{
    v1();

    Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
}
```

Which methods above are actually executed in parallel in the async/await generated lower thread pool if ButtonClick is called?

I mean, what should be my concerns about race conditions working with async/await? All async methods are mandatory executed in the same caller's thread? Should I use mutex on possible shared state? If yes, how could I detect what are the shared state objects?

Comment: By default all async continuations are executed in the same Synchronization context they've started. In console application there is no Synchronization context, and all the tasks will be run in a thread pool. So yes, you should be aware of race conditions. Shared state objects are the objects, which are being accessed in all the tasks.

Comment: Hello @VMAtm! So, the call graph will be executed in the same Synchronization Context (I'm considering this is the same as a thread) until it finds the first 'await' keyword? At this point (execution of the first 'await' in the call graph) the code bellow the 'await' will be executed in a different thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Which methods above are actually executed in parallel in the async/await generated lower thread pool if ButtonClick is called?

Only the `Console.WriteLine` within the `Task.Run`.

> I mean, what should be my concerns about race conditions working with async/await?

I suggest you start by reading my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which explains how `await` actually works.

In summary, `async` methods are usually written in a *serially asynchronous* fashion. Take this code for example:

```
CodeBeforeAwait();
await SomeOtherMethodAsync();
CodeAfterAwait();
```

You can always say that `CodeBeforeAwait` will execute to completion first, then `SomeOtherMethodAsync` will be called. Then our method will (asynchronously) wait for `SomeOtherMethodAsync` to complete, and only after that will `CodeAfterAwait` be called.

So it's serially asynchronous. It executes in a serial fashion, just like you'd expect it to, but also with an asynchronous point in that flow (the `await`).

Now, you *can't* say that `CodeBeforeAwait` and `CodeAfterAwait` will execute within the same thread, at least not without more context. `await` by default will resume in the current `SynchronizationContext` (or the current `TaskScheduler` if there is no SyncCtx). So, if the sample method above was executed in the UI thread, then you would know that `CodeBeforeAwait` and `CodeAfterAwait` will both execute on the UI thread. However, if it was executed without a context (i.e., from a background thread or Console main thread), then `CodeAfterAwait` may run on a different thread.

Note that even if parts of a method run on a different thread, the runtime takes care of putting any barriers in place before continuing the method, so there's no need to barrier around variable access.

Also note that your original example uses `Task.Run`, which explicitly places work on the thread pool. That's quite different than `async`/`await`, and you will definitely have to treat that as multithreaded.

> Should I use mutex on possible shared state?

Yes. For example, if your code uses `Task.Run`, then you'll need to treat that as a separate thread. (Note that with `await`, it's a *lot* easier to not share state at all with other threads - if you can keep your background tasks pure, they're much easier to work with).

> If yes, how could I detect what are the shared state objects?

Same answer as with any other kind of multi-threaded code: code inspection.

Comment: Hey Stephen, thanks for your very nice answer! So, summing up: all the awaits calls in a call graph will be executed in the same thread; the code will only be executed in another background thread if I explicit create a task via Task.Run or TaskCompletionSource? In other words, if I do not implement any method that will be executed via Task.Run all my code will execute in the same thread? Man, if the answer for the last question is yes: this is very beautiful! Thanks a lot, I will check out your article right now.

Comment: @ptr0x: Not quite; it will execute in the same *context*. If you only use a UI context, then yes, that has the same meaning as "same thread". But if you run the same code in a Console app, then no, it can be different threads. And if your code explicitly overrides the default context-capture behavior (i.e., `ConfigureAwait(false)`), then it may use the context or it may run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Got it. So I only have to take care of possible race conditions if I run the same code explicitly in different threads or initiating a task via Task.Run (which will execute the task in a thread pool thread), right?

Comment: I just read your article. Very much helpful and I found all the answers I needed there. Again: thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 2):

If you call an async function, your thread will perform this function until it reaches an await.

If you weren't using async-await, the thread would yield processing until the awaited code was finished and continue with the statement after the await.

But as you are using async-await, you told the compiler that whenever the thread has to wait for something, you have some other things it can do instead of waiting, The thread will do those other things until you say: now await until your original thing is finished.

Because of the call to an async function we are certain that somewhere inside there should be an await. Note that if you call an async function that doesn't await you get a compiler warning that the function will run synchronously.

Example:

```
private async void OnButton1_clickec(object sender, ...)
{
    string dataToSave = ...;
    var saveTask = this.MyOpenFile.SaveAsync(dataToSave);

    // the thread will go into the SaveAsync function and will
    // do all things until it sees an await.
    // because of the async SaveAsync we know there is somewhere an await
    // As you didn't say await this.MyOpenfile.SaveAsync
    // the thread will not wait but continue with the following
    // statements:

    DoSomethingElse()
    await saveTask;

    // here we see the await. The thread was doing something else,
    // finished it, and now we say: await. That means it waits until its
    // internal await is finished and continues with the statements after
    // this internal await.
```

Note that even if the await somewhere inside SaveAsync was finished, the thread will not perform the next statement until you await SaveTask. This has the effect that DoSomethingElse will not be interrupted if the await inside the SaveAsync was finished.

Therefore normally it's not useful to create an async function that does not return either a Task or a Task < TResult >
The only exception to this is an event handler. The GUI doesn't have to wait until your event handler is finished.

Comment: Thanks very much Harald! I will accept as the answer the reply of Stephen above just because his reply is a little bit more complete.